Title: System.EntryPointNotFoundException when initializing Steamworks.NET in C#
I'm trying to integrate Steamworks.NET into my C# application to utilize the Steam SDK functionalities. However, when I attempt to initialize Steamworks using SteamAPI.Init(), I encounter the following error:
**System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'SteamAPI_Init' in DLL 'steam_api64'.'
**
using System;
using Steamworks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initialize Steamworks
        if (!SteamAPI.Init())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Steamworks initialization failed!");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Steamworks initialized successfully!");

        // Call other Steamworks functions here

        // Shutdown Steamworks
        SteamAPI.Shutdown();
    }
}

Steps I've Tried:
DLL Location: I've verified that steam_api64.dll is located in the same directory as my executable.
Correct DLL Version: I'm using the correct version of steam_api64.dll that matches my Steamworks SDK version.
Steamworks.NET Integration: I've properly added Steamworks.NET (there was a nuGet for Steamworks by rileylabrecque ) to my project and ensured it references the correct version of steam_api64.dll.
Explicit DLL Loading: I've tried explicitly loading the Steam DLL using P/Invoke as suggested, but the issue persists.

I have been dealing with the same problem. I used a tool called Dependency Walker to break up the dll and see what functions are inside and I have reason to believe there might be a mismatch on the dlls. I am going to try and download the sdk again and see if they have updated the dll since the last time I got it. No idea. Seems like this should just work but of course its a hassle.

Have you had any luck yet?

https://github.com/rlabrecque/Steamworks.NET/issues/603

The solution that Hans gave, is not working
